# Why does my pattern extractor code return false positives?

Tags: python, web-scraping, biopython, ncbi, rentrez

My goal was to extract the sequence of "Antimicrobial Peptides" from the NCBI Database using keywords such as "Antimicrobial Peptides, AMPs" and also specifying its length.

I have written a code to extract the sequences of Antimicrobial Peptides (AMPs) from the NCBI protein database using the Biopython library.

### The Code

```py
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO

def scrape_fasta_sequence(keywords):
    # Provide your email address to NCBI
    Entrez.email = 'mabdullahafzal02@gmail.com'

    # Create the query string with filters
    query = f'{keywords} AND srcdb_refseq[PROP] AND 7:50[SLEN] '

    # Search for protein IDs that match the query
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='protein', term=query)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    id_list = record['IdList']

    # Use the protein IDs to fetch the sequences
    fasta_sequences = []
    for protein_id in id_list:
        handle = Entrez.efetch(db='protein', id=protein_id, rettype='fasta', retmode='text')
        fasta_sequence = SeqIO.read(handle, 'fasta')
        fasta_sequences.append(fasta_sequence)
        handle.close()

    return fasta_sequences

# Example usage
keywords = 'Antimicrobial Peptides OR AMPs'
fasta_sequences = scrape_fasta_sequence(keywords)
for fasta_sequence in fasta_sequences:
    print(fasta_sequence)
```

### Output

Output was not specific to the Antimicrobial Peptides. It provided me with other proteins which were not needed.
[output snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q2YF.png)

Kindly help, if code can be modified to add precision only towards antimicrobial peptides.

Comment: Please avoid attaching output as images, use code blocks instead.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a more specific filter to target Antimicrobial Peptides (AMPs). One way to do this is by specifying the source organism or using a specific keyword related to AMPs.
Here's an updated version of your code with an added filter for the source organism (bacteria, for example) and a specific keyword related to AMPs:

```
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO

def scrape_fasta_sequence(keywords):
    # Provide your email address to NCBI
    Entrez.email = 'mabdullahafzal02@gmail.com'

    # Create the query string with filters
    query = f'{keywords} AND srcdb_refseq[PROP] AND 7:50[SLEN] AND bacteria[ORGN]'

    # Search for protein IDs that match the query
    handle = Entrez.esearch(db='protein', term=query)
    record = Entrez.read(handle)
    id_list = record['IdList']

    # Use the protein IDs to fetch the sequences
    fasta_sequences = []
    for protein_id in id_list:
        handle = Entrez.efetch(db='protein', id=protein_id, rettype='fasta', retmode='text')
        fasta_sequence = SeqIO.read(handle, 'fasta')
        fasta_sequences.append(fasta_sequence)
        handle.close()

    return fasta_sequences

# Example usage
keywords = 'Antimicrobial Peptides OR AMPs'
fasta_sequences = scrape_fasta_sequence(keywords)
for fasta_sequence in fasta_sequences:
    print(fasta_sequence)
```

So output will be

```
ID: WP_328102937.1
Name: WP_328102937.1
Description: WP_328102937.1 acinetodin/klebsidin/J25 family lasso peptide, partial [Escherichia marmotae]
Number of features: 0
Seq('IFHLLKEDYINKKSASQLTKGGEVHVPEYFAGIGTPISFCG')
ID: WP_328101564.1
Name: WP_328101564.1
Description: WP_328101564.1 acinetodin/klebsidin/J25 family lasso peptide, partial [Escherichia marmotae]
Number of features: 0
Seq('KKSASQLTKGGEVHVPEYFAGIGTPISFCG')
....
....
and so on
```